# How to display all recipients in an email

Tags: email, smtp, reporting

I am currently using SMTP in a .net application to send files automatically when the user prompts the system

We have recipients setup to receive certian SSRS files, some clients want all and some clients only want one report. As such, the user just hits send and we send each client a single email with their requirements.

The issue is that since we have added this flexibility the clients have lost who is receiving the file.

Is there anyway to list all the receipients of an email in the to section or am I going to have to move all the recipients to the body of the email?